# Floating textbox design issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Ionic 4 - angular 7

[image]ion-item-bg - CSS

```
.ion-item-bg{
--background: transparent;
--color:#fff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff
```

}

```
<ion-item class="ion-item-bg" lines='none'>
                    <ion-label class="open-sans-light" position="floating" style="--color:#fff;">
                        email
                    </ion-label>
                    <ion-input formControlName='email' autocomplete='off'></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
```

If we save the credentials, then on reloading the UI looks like the image

Tried autocomplete off and all , but still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have only said what is wrong, not what you actually want.

I'm assuming you want the textbox to be transparent as well?

Looks like you need to style the `ion-input`.

```
ion-input {
  --background: transparent;
}
```

If that doesn't work sometimes I've had to use:

```
ion-input {
  --background: transparent;
  background: transparent;
}
```

Or even put `!important;`'s on them.

Comment: I need to remove the 'grey' background. I am facing this issue only when  the credentials are stored. In incognito window i am not facing this issue (All Browsers)